# jquery datatables "search" returns previously deleted data

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, datatables

Im using an onclick to delete selected rows from sql database and update the datatable simultaneously by sending an ajax to the php/server.
Responsible for deleting the record is some backend php.

So far so good.

However,when i try to search,it returns back the rows i have deleted,what should i do ?

```
$(document).on('click', '#delete', function() {
        var id = $(this).parent().find("#id").text();
        var name = $(this).parent().find("#name").text();
         
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete record " + id + " with name " + name + " ?")){
         
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/indexDB/actions.php",
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    deletename: name
                }
            })
            .done(function(msg) {
                alert(msg);                
                 
$("#dtVerticalScrollExample tbody").empty();       //EMPTY THE DB WINDOW
     
$.ajax({                                                                 //POPULATE DB WINDOW AGAIN
        url: 'http://localhost/indexDB/ajaxfile.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response){
            var len = response.length;
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var id = response[i].id;
                var name = response[i].name;
                var contents = response[i].contents;
                var date = response[i].date;
                var ajaxbutton = response[i].button;
                 
                var button = document.createElement("i");
                button.className = "far fa-trash-alt trashdb";
 
                var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                    "<td id=id>" + id + "</td>" +
                    "<td id=name>" + name + "</td>" +
                    "<td id=date>" + date + "</td>" +
                    "<td id=buttonrow>" + button.outerHTML + "</tr>";
 
                $("#dtVerticalScrollExample tbody").append(tr_str);
            }
 
        }
    });
  });
    }else{
        alert("Delete cancelled !")
    }
         
 
    });   //DELETE RECORDS FROM DB
```

Comment: Call `$(tableSelectorHere).DataTable()` again, after your change.